# Shipping Homemade Mozzarella

Tags: food-safety, vacuum, mozzarella

I would like to ship homemade mozzarella. I'm considering purchasing a vacuum packaging system to preserve it for the 2-3 day trip. Is this recommended? If not, are there any alternatives?

Comment: Are you also planning to ship it with dry ice or some other form of cooling?

Comment: What are the outside temps where you're living right now? What are the temps where it's going too? If you're in the 30's - 40's F. Then I wouldn't be worried about it. If higher or lower than that, then it's all relative.

Comment: You say "a vacuum packaging system to preserve it". If you believe that vacuum packaging preserves food, you are missing some very basic knowledge in food safety. My suggestion is that you take a proper course in food safety, it may even be required by the local authorities if you are setting up a business.

Answer (score 3):

Mozzarella needs to be refrigerated, outside the fridge it has a limited shelf life, see our generic question: [How do I know if food left at room temperature is still safe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat)

So shipping without some means of cooling will result in an unsafe product, look into shipping methods for perishable products. Your local mail or parcel carrier should be able to assist you.